# How to link an unchanging Wix URL to a PDF that will be replaced with updated versions

Tags: url, pdf

As an example, the URL https://nationalmtb.org/nica-handbook always links to the most updated version of the organization's handbook (currently a file named `NICA-Handbook.12.1.23.v2.pdf`).

How do I do the same, having a URL like `example.com/myorg-handbook` link to whatever the current version is? I am using Wix for our website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Wix's Redirect Manager in their SEO Tools to [create a manual redirect](https://support.wix.com/en/article/setting-up-a-301-redirect-for-a-page-on-your-site#manually-creating-a-301-redirect-for-a-page).

This would allow you to update the redirect when you upload new versions of the file.

There are a couple of caveats though:

1. You have to have a custom domain configured
2. They are always created as 301 permanent redirects, which means you might not see updates if you use the original redirect, change the location and then test again as your browser can cache the original redirect.

To create a 301 redirect:

- Go to your SEO Dashboard.
- Select Go to URL Redirect Manager under Tools and settings.
- Click + New Redirect.
- Select Single redirect.
- Enter the path you want to redirect from (e.g. `/myorg-handbook`) under Old URL.
- Enter the new URL that you want to redirect to:

  - You will probably need to enter the full URL to the PDF on your site, as they probably don't have slugs for the finder to use.
- Click Save, or click Save & Add Another to add more.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would continue to link to the most current version with the URL above. For all the other versions, I would create a page on the site to house links to past versions for easier viewing.

This will probably be the easiest way to manage it. You will already have to host the PDF somewhere, even if you were able to dynamically do it. So instead of creating a custom process, you would just have to add a link when a new version is available.

Comment: This wouldn't be the best solution for our purposes, as the handbook gets linked to in other places besides our website (emails, google docs, etc). I'd like it so that we don't need to have to update the link in documents that get updated from year to year.

Answer (score 1):

Wix primarily supports embedding files like PDFs using the "File" element. Here's a general guide on how to embed a PDF in Wix:

**Upload PDF to Wix:**

- Log in to your Wix account and go to the Wix Editor.
- Click on the page where you want to embed the PDF. Click on "Add" on
  the left sidebar.
- Select "More" and then choose "File" from the list.
- Upload your PDF file using the File Upload dialog.

**Embed the PDF:**

- Click on the added "File" element on your page.
- In the Settings panel on the right, you'll see an option for "File."
- Choose the PDF file you uploaded.

**Adjust Display Settings (Optional):**

- You can customize the display settings of the embedded PDF, such as the icon, text, and link style.

**Save and Publish:**

- Save your changes in the Wix Editor.
- Publish your site to make the changes live.